# Define a SQL query to call on

Tags: php, sql, forms

Say I have the following php code:

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname FROM contact WHERE '{$_REQUEST['userid']}' = contactid";
$rs = $conn->Execute($sql);
if (!$rs) {
print $conn->ErrorMsg();
}
else {
while (!$rs->EOF) {
print $rs->fields[0].'<br>';
$rs->MoveNext();  //  Moves to the next row
}}
```

Which works well, however, how can I define that scrip/code to have the following in my form:

```
<p>First Name: <?php $whatever_it_can_be ?></p>
```

Comment: Inserting `{$_REQUEST['userid']}` into your SQL statement is dangerous because it will allow SQL injection.

Comment: The sample code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). To fix this hole, switch to prepared statements. If your DB class doesn't support them, try [PDO](http://php.net/PDO), [which does](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements). If you need a PDO tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html). The site you save may just be your own.

Comment: Where are `fields[1]` and `fields[2]` coming from?

Comment: Sorry, about fields[1] and [2], ignore just an error.

Comment: Thank you for the security risk info. Still, what would be a good way or better way to call for the field in a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else {
    if (!$rs->EOF) {
        $firstname = $rs->fields[0];
    } else {
        // user id is invalid
    }
}
```

Then in the page:

```
<p>First Name: <?php echo $firstname; ?></p>
```

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, click the checkmark under the vote count on the upper left to mark as accepted.